# HP DL180 G6 - SD Card slot

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, sd-card

I have `ESXi 5` installed on **HP DL180 G6** on RAID. This server is part of the `vCenter` and it's connected with **HP P2000 Storage**. For some reason all VMs on that server a very slow and "restart" of the host or "restart" of guest are taking a lot of time. I think that the problem is RAID issue and slows down the host.
I am thinking to install the ESXi on SD card but I couldn't find if the DL180 has a slot for SD. Since the server is remotely I can't open it and check it out.
Anyone knows for sure that Dl180 G6 has an SD Card Slot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that model didn't ship with an SD card slot.

In terms of your actual problem do you mean HP P2000? if so which version and which connectivity option (i.e. FC, SAS etc.)

The DL180 G6 shipped with a few disk controller options (P410, on-board etc.) but I'm pretty sure no standard configuration offered external SAS ports so we could do with knowing the layout of the server config. If you're only using the internal SAS card for say a pair of mirrored boot disks then I'd suggest you do a clean installation to see if that helps.

Comment: Hi, Yes its P2000 and the VMs are on the storage. I have installed a SAS controller to support it. The issue is on the host and the installation of the ESXi which is installed on the internal disk-RAID

Comment: I do so hate shared-bus-SAS for VMWare - I know it 'works' and is on the HCL but FC/FCoE/iSCSI/NFS seems so much more reliable.

Comment: What you recomend? Rebuild the RAID and install again or should I try to install it on a USB?

Comment: If you can take the hosts out for long enough I'd shut it down, run an SPP on it to update all the various firmware, delete the boot virtual disk in disk controller and recreate a new R1 mirror with the boot disks, run diags on them to see if they're fine, if they are reinstall ESXi onto them and reconfigure as needed - and see how you get on. I'm assuming you have a second host on the same P2000? if so then do the same on that once the first one is back. Oh and check that the firmware is up to date on the P2000 and it's disks too of course.